# How to alter address bar URL while I'm in a different website?

Tags: javascript, security, url

Let's say I'm on a `https://www.example.com`. Can I alter address bar `URL` to display `https://www.google.com` while I'm in `https://www.example.com` website using `JavaScript`?

ex:

I'm on `https://www.example.com` website, But what if I wanna display different URL like `http://www.google.com` in the address bar? Is it possible?

*Just asking based on learning purpose about the information security.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be a security risk, if any website could make it appear to the user to actually be on any other website. Phishing would be a whole lot easier if that was permitted.

The best you can do is [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) (or `.replaceState`), which has the reasonable restriction that:

> The new URL can be any URL in the same origin as the current URL.

Or, of course, you could actually redirect to the other website by assigning to `location.href`.

It might be possible to write a browser extension that fiddles with the internals of the browser so that it displays your arbitrary desired text instead of the actual current page, but such a thing would have to be deliberately installed by the user.